# The future of deprecated special variables

Tags: perl, deprecated, special-variables

Are deprecated special variables (like `$#` and `$*`) lost forever or would it be possible the reuse them in a future Perl version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason why they couldn't be reused if an appropriate `use 5.16` or some such is present, but that would be terribly unlikely. Firstly because it's just asking for trouble (it will confuse the hell out of people), secondly because special variables are a nasty thing anyway and introducing a new one is rarely a good idea. You can probably consider them *lost forever*.

Comment: I'd like one, that returns `"\x{27}"` for one-liners in the linux-command-line.

Comment: @sid_com: why would you need that? You may want to try the q operator to avoid needing them in the first place.

Comment: But in these cases I can't use the q operator: `perl -E 'say "normal '\''single'\'' normal '\''quoted'\'' normal"'`

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem using them in versions of Perl where they have been deprecated.

I use the `$*` variable in my module [Whatever](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Whatever) that creates a Perl6-ish whatever-star (`*`) for Perl 5.

Be sure to use glob aliasing to assign to the variable.  That will circumvent any deprecated warnings and will remove any tie magic from the variable.

```
** = \"\x{27}";  # assigns to $*
```

If you wanted to do this tersly from the command line, you could put that line in a module:

In file 'q.pm' installed into your perl library path:

```
** = \"\x{27}";
```

Then you could write:

```
perl -Mq -e '... use $* here ...'
```

Comment: After rereading my question I saw that was I meant is not clearly expressed. I meant provided from Perl as a new build-in special variable. Writing my own variable is to inconvenient for the command-line (except there is a great deal of `'`'s, but then I wouldn't need a special variable).